# Binomial Expansion without inifinty series

Tags: binomial-theorem

Variable here is "a" and "b".The question is to simplify the $\sqrt [3] { (\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^3} })\times {\frac {\sqrt{a^6b^2}}{a} }+ \frac{a}{b^2}}$

So these are my steps

=$\left(\frac {a^3b} {b^\frac {3} {2} }+ \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

=$\left({a^3b^{1-\frac {3} {2}} } + \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

=$\left({a^3b^\frac {-1} {2} } + \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

Now the real question is,how to simplify this?Assuming the both fraction is simplified to "x" and "y",I get $(x+y)^\frac {1} {3}$ but my family said that it is expanded to this:

$(x+y)^\frac {1} {3}=x^\frac {1} {3}+y^\frac {1} {3}$
It should not be this because $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$

The thing is I noticed where $(x+y)^n$ have a pattern called pascal triangle.But this can be only applied when n≥1 where n is a integer.

The problem with the binomial theorem is that the answer is infinite,which I do not want to get this.I need to get an answer where it is not infinite and does not involve any roots.How do I simplify this?

I have checked with Issac Newton theory,but the Issac Newton theory is infinite.

I have searched online and I see is infinite answer: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054926/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54582.html)

If this is impossible to simplify without avoiding infinite series,is there another method to solve the question,$\sqrt [3] { (\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^3} })\times {\frac {\sqrt{a^6b^2}}{a} }+ \frac{a}{b^2}}$?

Comment: It is very difficult to read

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici apologies,I never learn to put mathematically in internet.Can u find a way to edit the main question?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I would prefer someone to ans the expanding of (x+y)^1/3 without the answer being infinite than the top question.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to say that "x" means "times" and later say "x" is an expression. Normally "times" is not written in mathematics but if you want to make it explicit use `\times` in LaTeX.

Comment: @user21820 shall re-edit.Thanks!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I would really like to help you but I cannot read the text and I suppose I am not the only one. Moreover, I am almost blind !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici here,I have edited the top.I will continue editing thanks user 21820.Apologies.Do you know the function for Cube root?

Comment: see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: `\sqrt[3]{x}` for $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici edited by me. done, you may view the ques. now.

Comment: @ADG sorry!I edited it again to a more clearer and simplified view.Thanks for your effort though!My first time doing this edit sorry!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you can now view the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,
$$(x+y)^{1/3}\ne x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}$$
For example, take $x=y=1$. If this weren't true, we'd have $\sqrt[3]2=2$.

In fact, if $x$ and $y$ are positive, we have:
$$(x+y)^{1/3}<x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}$$

Comment: Yes,but I wanted to know is how do I simplify $(x+y)^\frac {1} {3}$ .

Comment: @ministic2001 That's as simplified as you can get it. (Newton has a theorem that let's you expand it into an infinite series, but I wouldn't call that "simplifying.")

Comment: You mean,there is no way to remove that power of $\frac {1} {3}$ ?Because I would not want infinite series too

Comment: Okay,nevermind.Do you know how to solve the main question $\sqrt [3] { (\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^3} })\times {\frac {\sqrt{a^6b^2}}{a} }+ \frac{a}{b^2}}$
 then?

Comment: It seems to be $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{a^3}{\sqrt b}+\dfrac a{b^2}}$.

Comment: I think I'd want to rationalize the denominator for the fraction on the left. (Are you sure it says $+$, by the way?) PS That's equivalent to what you had — do you see why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is $+$,which is annoying and confusing for a Singaporean student secondary 2 :P

Comment: @ministic2001 Perhaps you're also meant to combine the fractions?

Comment: OH MAY GAWD LOL YES!How on earth did I not known this?

Comment: Oh wait,not yet.Even if I combine the fraction it still have this
$(\frac {a^3b^\frac {1} {2} + a } {b^2})^\frac {1} {3}$

Comment: @ministic2001 Which is $\displaystyle\sqrt[\large{3}]{\frac{a^3\sqrt b+a}{b^2}}$, which I don't think can be simplified much further.